# Aumentar +1 no banco de dados

Tags: php, mysql

Bom, queria contar +1 no mysql, e não estou conseguindo.

Código abaixo

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","asdasd","dbb");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$valor = mysqli_query ($con, "SELECT * site_stats (item) VALUES");  
$novoValor = $valor + 1;  

mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM site_stats");
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO site_stats (item) VALUES ('$novoValor')");

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Use [auto_increment](http://www.bosontreinamentos.com.br/mysql/mysql-auto-incremento-de-valores-em-colunas-08/)

Comment: Já estou usando, mas por algum motivo ele não está subindo +1

Comment: Tá querendo inserir ou atualizar (update) um registro?

Comment: Por exemplo, o sistema que quero fazer é ele ter da 1 visualização e após isso quando alguém visualizar novamente aumentar +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Além da forma já mostrada, você também pode fazer com o seguinte código:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "asdasd", "dbb") or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error());

mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE `site_stats` SET `item` = `item`+1");
```

Irá funcionar da mesma forma.

Answer (score 1):

**Apenas corrigindo seu código ficaria assim:**

**PHP**

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","asdasd","dbb");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$consulta = "SELECT item FROM site_stats";  

$result = $con->query($consulta);


while($dados = $result->fetch_array()){
//retorna o valor do campo item
   $valor = $dados["item"];
} 
$novoValor = $valor + 1;  

//atualiza o campo item
$sql = "UPDATE site_stats SET item = '$novoValor'";
$data = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

mysqli_close($con);
```